# Method testing a Calculator

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, uwp

I have this calculator that i made in UWP. It can add, multiply, subtract, do divisions, convert Celsius to Fahrenheit and vice versa.

My problem is that i need a way to test it so that i can add, sub, divide, multiply in one test method.
And also test so that i can take a Celsius value and convert it to Fahrenheit, all in a test method.

I can change it so that some of my methods become public instead of private, but i don't know how i should go about testing some of these?

My testmethods are at the top of the code.

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Reflection;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;


// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace Calc
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A calculator, namespace start. 
    /// </summary>
    /// 

    
    /// Public start, mainpage. 
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {


       
        /// Input for Celcius/Farh.
        string input;


        /// <summary>
        /// Testing celcius / F.
        /// </summary>
        [TestMethod]
         private void TestDifferentScales()
          {
          
          }


        /// <summary>
        /// Test method - testing all functions regarding mathematical equations!
        /// </summary>
        [TestMethod()]
        public void AdditionTest()
        {
            
           
            
        }




        /// <summary>
        /// Start main program!
        /// </summary>
        public MainPage()
        {
            //Startar allt.
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Button for number 1.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            textBox.Text += '1';
            input += "1";
          
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Button for number 2.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text += '2';
            input += "2";

        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Button for number 3.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text += '3';
            input += "3";
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Button for number 4.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text += '4';
            input += "4";

        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Button for number 5.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Button_Click_4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text += '5';
            input += "5";
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Button for number 6.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Button_Click_5(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text += '6';
            input += "6";

        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Button for number 7.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Button_Click_6(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text += '7';
            input += "7";

        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Button for number 8.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Button_Click_7(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text += '8';
            input += "8";
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Button for number 9.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Button_Click_8(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text += '9';
            input += "9";

        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Button for numbers 42 "Marcus".
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Button_Click_9(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text += "42";
            input += "42";
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Button for number 0.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Button_Click_10(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text += '0';
            input += "0";
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Button for multiplication of equation "F = M*A".
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Button_Click_11(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            /* F = M * A 
             * Denna ekvation är simpel och man lär sig den redan i början utav Fysik 1.
             * Ekvationen är inte specifik, så som tex "F = M * G" då gravitationen kan bli ett "fixed" värde som 
             * går mellan 9,802 och 9,820.
             * Anledningen till varför denna är så simpel är för att jag ville bevisa att det gick att ha många komplikaitoner 
             * i ett knapp tryck. Så denna skulle lika gärna kunnat vara knappen för multiplikation.
             */
            textBox.Text += '*';

        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Button for addition.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Button_ClickPlus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            /* "Exceptions without Execeptions"
             * Här försökte jag att gå runt utan att behöva använda en 
             * try/catch eller Exception inför min "data table" på min "=" knapp.
             * Men, som sagt, det är ingen skillnad här och på min knapp för "F = M * A".
             * Det finns ju klara skillander, jag har försökt att se till så att jag går tillbaka ett
             * steg ifall det finns flera matematiska karaktärer. 
             * 
             * MEN: Det skapar problem då jag fortfarande ville kunna köra "6--1 = 7" utan att krasha allt.
             * 
             */
            var last = textBox.Text;
            if (last[last.Length - 1] != '+' || last[last.Length - 1] != '-' || last[last.Length - 1] != '*' || last[last.Length - 1] != '/')
            {
                textBox.Text += '+';
            }
            else
            {
                textBox.Text = last.Remove(last.Length - 1, 1);
                textBox.Text += '+';
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Button for subtraction. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Button_ClickMinus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var last = textBox.Text;
            if (last[last.Length - 1] != '+' || last[last.Length - 1] != '-' || last[last.Length - 1] != '*' || last[last.Length - 1] != '/')
            {
                textBox.Text += '-';
            }
            else
            {
                textBox.Text = last.Remove(last.Length - 1, 1);
                textBox.Text += '-';
            }
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Button for multiplication.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Button_ClickTimes(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var last = textBox.Text;
            if (last[last.Length - 1] != '+' || last[last.Length - 1] != '-' || last[last.Length - 1] != '*' || last[last.Length - 1] != '/')
            {
                textBox.Text += '*';
            }
            else
            {
                textBox.Text = last.Remove(last.Length - 1, 1);
                textBox.Text += '*';
            }
        }
        

        /// <summary>
        /// Button for division. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Button_ClickDEv(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var last = textBox.Text;
            if (last[last.Length - 1] != '+' || last[last.Length - 1] != '-' || last[last.Length - 1] != '*' || last[last.Length - 1] != '/')
            {
                textBox.Text += '/';
            }
            else
            {
                textBox.Text = last.Remove(last.Length - 1, 1);
                textBox.Text += '/';
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Button for "Equal", the equal button.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Button_ClickEqual(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            /* Exception.
             * Jag prövade att unit testa här med en thread timer för att kunna 
             * skriva ett meddelande i boxen typ "Error: Please try again" 
             * och sen rensa allt, men det gav error, det funkade men jag ville
             * inte ha något error med så jag tog bort den från min "catch".
             * 
             */
            try
            {
             object q = new DataTable().Compute(textBox.Text, null);
                        textBox.Text = q.ToString();
            }
            catch
            {
             
                /*
                 * Här återställer jag bara allt.  
                 */
           
                textBox.Text = string.Empty;
                input = string.Empty;
            }
           
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Button for reset of calcuator.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Button_ClickReset(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            /*
             * Åter ställer här på "ClickReset" också.
             */
            textBox.Text = string.Empty;
            input = string.Empty;

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Button from  F to C.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Button_Click_fc_(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            /*
             * Här så var jag tvungen att gå fram och tillbaka med att 
             * konvertera saker från och till int och string. 
             * Multiplicerade och addade 32 eller tog bort 32 för att
             * få rätt värden i slutet. 
             */
            int value = int.Parse(input);
            int after = value - 32; 
            int a = (int)(decimal.Divide(after, (decimal)1.8));
            string answer = a.ToString();
            textBox.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox.Text = answer;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Button from C to F.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        public void Button_Click_cf_(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int value = int.Parse(input);
            int a = (int)(decimal.Multiply(value, (decimal)1.8) + 32);
            string answer = a.ToString();
            textBox.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox.Text = answer; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In general, your tests should be in a different unit test project. For better testability, you want to abstract all the calculator logic into another class, where the main functionality would be exposed as public methods which you can test independently from the UI.

Comment: Checkout MVVM pattern, then testing should be easy :)

Comment: See [Calculator with WPF (Code Review)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101003/calculator-with-wpf).

Comment: I can give you a comprehensive method by which you combine multiplication, division, addition, subtraction, and parentheses, but you need to know something about converting infix expressions to postfix. Of course it is very simple

Comment: @meysamasadi That would be nice!

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you an example that relieves you of user input. You only have to allow certain characters at the entrance.
If you know about converting **infix** expressions to **postfix**, understanding the example is great.

*And you produce the most advanced calculator with the least code.*

> ***Input phrases should not have a space character, in which case delete the spaces.***

**Step 1. The following lines show how to use**

```
//real example in world
string infix = "(((13+26)*12)-15+15*(20/6))";
List<string> arrayPostfix;
            
if (ValidBraces(infix))
{
    convertToPostfixArray(ref infix, out arrayPostfix);
    double result = calculate(arrayPostfix);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("invalid experssion***********************");
```

**Step 2. Method for checking the validity of Braces**

```
static bool ValidBraces(string infix)
{
   bool valid = true;
   int i = 0;
   Stack<char> symbls = new Stack<char>();

   while (i < infix.Length)
   {
       if (infix[i] == '(')
           symbls.Push(infix[i]);

       if (infix[i] == ')')
           if (symbls.Count == 0)
           {
              valid = false;
              break;
           }
           else
           {
               char ch = symbls.Pop();
               if (ch != '(')
               {
                  valid = false;
                  break;
               }
           }

           i++;
   }

   if (symbls.Count > 0)
       valid = false;

   return valid;
}
```

**Step 3. Method for converting infix expressions to postfix**

```
static bool convertToPostfixArray(ref string infix, out List<string> postfix)
{
    int prio = 0;
    postfix = new List<string>();
    Stack<Char> s1 = new Stack<char>();
    string value = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < infix.Length; i++)
    {
        char ch = infix[i];
        if (ch == '(')
        {  
           s1.Push(ch);                     
        }
        else if (ch == ')')
        {
           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
           {
               postfix.Add(value);
               value = string.Empty;
           }
           while (s1.Peek() != '(')
           {
               postfix.Add(s1.Pop().ToString());
           }
           s1.Pop();
        }
        else if (ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '*' || ch == '/')
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                postfix.Add(value);
                value = string.Empty;
            }
            if (s1.Count <= 0)
            {
                s1.Push(ch);
            }
            else
            {
                if (s1.Peek() == '*' || s1.Peek() == '/')
                    prio = 1;
                else
                    prio = 0;
                if (prio == 1)
                {
                   char c = s1.Peek();
                   if (c != '(')
                       postfix.Add(s1.Pop().ToString());
                   i--;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (ch == '+' || ch == '-')
                    {
                        char c = s1.Peek();
                        if (c != '(')
                          postfix.Add(s1.Pop().ToString());
                        s1.Push(ch);
                    }
                    else
                       s1.Push(ch);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            value += ch.ToString();
        }
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        postfix.Add(value);
        value = string.Empty;
    }

    int len = s1.Count;
    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
    {
       char c = s1.Pop();
       if (c != '(')
          postfix.Add(c.ToString());
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Step 4. Postfix calculation method**

```
static double calculate(List<string> postfix)
{
   Stack<double> stack = new Stack<double>();
   foreach (string item in postfix)
   {
       double answer = 0;
       if (item == "+" || item == "-" || item == "*" || item == "/")
       {
          char charVal = System.Convert.ToChar(item);
          double operand1 = ((Double)stack.Pop());
          double operand2 = ((Double)stack.Pop());

          answer = Solve(charVal, operand1, operand2);
          stack.Push((answer));
       }
       else
       {
           stack.Push(Convert.ToDouble(item));
       }
   }
   return stack.Pop();
}
public static double Solve(char operation, double operand1, double operand2)
{
    double answer = 0;
    switch (operation)
    {
        case '+':
          answer = operand1 + operand2;
          break;
        case '-':
          answer = operand2 - operand1;
          break;
        case '*':
          answer = operand1 * operand2;
          break;
        case '/':
          answer = operand2 / operand1;
          break;
    }
    return answer;
}
```